# Can't get specific page facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with facebook graph to get a certain page's feed
The problem is that multiple pages work except one. If I try this page: 850172888338672 in the graph API toolkit everything works fine and I can get the feed. When I try to access it by https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/850172888338672/feed?access_token=*** , it doesn't work. There is no problem with my accesstoken because I can get any other page I tried by exchanging the page id. How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Which access token are you using ?

Comment: I actually  found out that I can't access it with a app acces token due to acces rights so I now work with an extended user acces token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the page access token. you have to use the user access token with all the related scopes.